# Pair each value in a row with other rows in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-3.8

I have a dataframe of 500 rows sorted as follows:

```
Col1    Val1
asd     0.27
pqer    0.37
psdf    0.54
```

I am trying to pair each value of `Col1` with another row in `Col1` who have higher `Val1` to get the following list:

```
[['asd', 'pqer'], ['asd','psdf'],['pqer','psdf']]
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try self merge and filtering:

```
df.merge(df, how='cross')\
  .query('Val1_x < Val1_y')[['Col1_x','Col1_y']]\
  .to_numpy().tolist()
```

Output:

```
[['asd', 'pqer'], ['asd', 'psdf'], ['pqer', 'psdf']]
```

Answer (score 1):

A binary search could be more efficient than a cartesian join (dependent on the data size); [conditional_join](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) can help with this:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor


(df.conditional_join(df, ('Val1', 'Val1', '<'))
   .loc(axis=1)[:, 'Col1']
   .to_numpy()
   .tolist()
)

 [['asd', 'pqer'], ['asd', 'psdf'], ['pqer', 'psdf']]
```